# Rotate the div at an angle using javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation, angle

I want to rotate the div by an angle, say 60 degrees, clockwise using javascript.

Across a lot of links via google, a logical solution seems using the Math library, but I don't know how to implement the above problem. Trigonometry was never my cup of tea :|

It can be done easily via jQuery, but I'm not allowed to use any of the libraries.
Upon googling, i had come across sandpaper,etc. but have to do it with available javascript functions.
Also, since it's on IE6, CSS3 cannot be used. :/

So, say I want to rotate the test div by an angle, how do i go about it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>#test {background:#000; width:100px; height:100px;}</style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: you mean rotate ? or move actually ?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant rotating it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, try this.  This spins a box (in IE8) and should work in IE6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IE6 rotation test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #spinner {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                left: 100px;
                width: 200px;
                height: 100px;
                border: 2px solid red;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand')
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var spinnerAngle = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        spinnerAngle += Math.PI / 64;
        setElementAngle(document.getElementById('spinner'), spinnerAngle);
    }, 25);
}

function setElementAngle(ele, radians)
{
     costheta = Math.cos(radians);
     sintheta = Math.sin(radians);

     ele.filters.item(0).M11 = costheta;
     ele.filters.item(0).M12 = -sintheta;
     ele.filters.item(0).M21 = sintheta;
     ele.filters.item(0).M22 = costheta;
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="spinner"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See [the documentation for the Matrix filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The "sizingMethod" setting is apparently necessary.

Comment: Yeah, i"ve checked that, however the problem is that in IE, the above  allows only one of four angled rotations, 0,90,180,270.

Comment: @Aaditi, I got spinning to work in IE using the code in my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works smooth on IE8+, however, does not run  on IE7...IE is seriously a pain. I was trying a different approach now, as in via javascript with Math library, will post it here if I get successful.